# 2-particle irreducible (2PI) feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, software

Let me preface this by saying that I'm not too code-savvy, which is probably why I need to ask this here. As a first step, I want to find a way to generate 2-particle irreducible (2PI) Feynman diagrams in Mathematica or Python for a specific theory, the Feynman rules of which I can give as an input, or even just for qed/ $\phi^4$ is fine. Is there some package that does this, or could you maybe point me to the direction of how to implement this myself?

Comment: Software requests are generally considered off-topic, though asking for resources on building your own library ought to be on-topic.